# Django REST framework flat, read-write serializer

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

In Django REST framework, what is involved in creating a flat, read-write serializer representation? The docs refer to a 'flat representation' (end of the section http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#dealing-with-nested-objects) but don't offer examples or anything beyond a suggestion to use a `RelatedField` subclass.

For instance, how to provide a flat representation of the `User` and `UserProfile` relationship, below?

```
# Model
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favourite_number = models.IntegerField()

# Serializer
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serialisers.EmailField(source='user.email')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['id', 'favourite_number', 'email',]
```

The above `UserProfileSerializer` doesn't allow writing to the `email` field, but I hope it expresses the intention sufficiently well. So, how should a 'flat' read-write serializer be constructed to allow a writable `email` attribute on the `UserProfileSerializer`? Is it at all possible to do this when subclassing ModelSerializer?

Thanks.

Comment: I found valuable answer here too [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381700/django-rest-framework-how-do-you-flatten-nested-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381700/django-rest-framework-how-do-you-flatten-nested-data)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the Django REST framework (DRF) source I settled on the view that a DRF serializer is strongly tied to an accompanying Model for unserializing purposes. `Field`'s `source` param make this less so for serializing purposes.

With that in mind, and viewing serializers as encapsulating validation and save behaviour (in addition to their (un)serializing behaviour) I used two serializers: one for each of the User and UserProfile models:

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email',]

class UserProfileSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['id', 'favourite_number', 'email',]
```

The `source` param on the `EmailField` handles the serialization case adequately (e.g. when servicing GET requests). For unserializing (e.g. when serivicing PUT requests) it is necessary to do a little work in the view, combining the validation and save behaviour of the two serializers:

```
class UserProfileRetrieveUpdate(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only UserProfileSerializer is required to serialize data since
        # email is populated by the 'source' param on EmailField.
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(
                instance=request.user.get_profile())
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Both UserSerializer and UserProfileSerializer are required
        # in order to validate and save data on their associated models.
        user_profile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(
                instance=request.user.get_profile(),
                data=request.DATA)
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(
                instance=request.user,
                data=request.DATA)
        if user_profile_serializer.is_valid() and user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_profile_serializer.save()
            user_serializer.save()
            return Response(
                    user_profile_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        # Combine errors from both serializers.
        errors = dict()
        errors.update(user_profile_serializer.errors)
        errors.update(user_serializer.errors)
        return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Paul, is your request.DATA here a single JSON nested array, or do you have one for each of the models in the POST request? (Am trying to achieve something similar)

Comment: @jvc26, my example above would use a single root JSON object in `request.DATA`. `request.DATA` would look something like this:
    `{ 'id': '1', 'favourite_number': '2', 'email': 'me@example.com' }`
As far as the client is concerned, that JSON object represents a single model instance, and will have no knowledge of the two models (`User` and `UserProfile`) that it actually breaks down to on the server. `UserSerializer` and `UserProfileSerializer` are used to extract, validate and save content from request.DATA for their associated models.

Answer (score 2):

First: better handling of nested writes is on it's way.

Second: The [Serializer Relations docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html) say of both `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and `SlugRelatedField` that "By default this field is read-write..." — so if your email field was unique (is it?) it might be you could use the `SlugRelatedField` and it would just work — I've not tried this yet (however).

Third: Instead I've used a plain `Field` subclass that uses the [`source="*"` technique](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments) to accept the whole object. From there I manually pull the related field in `to_native` and return that — this is read-only. In order to write I've checked request.DATA in `post_save` and updated the related object there — This isn't automatic but it works.

So, Fourth: Looking at what you've already got, my approach (above) amounts to marking your `email` field as read-only and then implementing `post_save` to check for an `email` value and perform the update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @carton-gibson. (1) I shall look forward to easier writes on nested representations. (2) My example is simplified for illustration, but your suggestion is interesting. (3 & 4) Doing some post_save() fiddling had occurred to me, and I've used that in other situations, but using two serializers (my own answer) seems cleaner and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not strictly answer the question - I think it will solve your need. The issue may be more in the split of two models to represent one entity than an issue with DRF.

Since Django 1.5, you can make a custom user, if all you want is some method and extra fields but apart from that you are happy with the Django user, then all you need to do is:

`class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    favourite_number = models.IntegerField()`

and in settings: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.myuser'`

(And of course a db-migration, which could be made quite simple by using `db_table` option to point to your existing user table and just add the new columns there).

After that, you have the common case which DRF excels at.