# Use CreateAPIView when having all model fields implicit (django-rest-framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following scenario:

I have a FooModel, a FooModelSerializer serializer and a AddFooObject view which inherits the CreateAPIView generic view in which I would like to add a record to the DB. My problem is that all the fields from the FooModel are implicit (information like the current time, system information, etc.). I tried solving this by adding them inside the `pre_save` method, but the flow does not get there because when it receives the request, it looks for the fields existing the model and it does not find them, thus returning `HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST` and `"foo_field": ["This field is required."]`.

Is there a chance of using the generic view, exclude all the fields from the model and add them only in the `pre_save` method or should I use normal views?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you put some code? What did you try? What do you mean by implicit field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark each of the fields that you will set implicitly in `pre_save` as `read_only`. This will stop them being treated as required and so eliminate the error.

See [the docs on the serializer field core arguments](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments) for more info.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! Indeed, this was what I was trying to do, but after some debugging I found out that I was doing the changes to the wrong serializer class. They have similar names, I am pretty tired so it all added up. Stupid mistake! Anyway, thanks again! :)

Comment: for an example with code on HOW to use read_only see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18456557/579646