# Registration of an extended user through POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django v1.7dev with the Django Rest Framework v2.3

I have extended the user Class as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   gang = models.ForeignKey('Gang', related_name='gangsters')

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I have also created a User serializer endpoint (which does not show the password when I sent a GET request, but accepts it when I send a post, with the purpose of using it for registration:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email')


def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
    user.set_password(attrs['password'])
    return user

def to_native(self, obj):
    ret = super(UserSerializer, self).to_native(obj)
    del ret['password']
    return ret
```

I'd love to extend the serializer to include also the gang parameter. Something similar to

```
gang = serializers.Field(source='profile.gang')
```

but writable instead of ReadOnly, so that when I register a user I can insert also the gang, possibly in an atomic way. What is the best approach in this case? I have tried to play a bit with other fields types, but unsuccessfully till now.
At the moment I am sending two separate post (one for User and one for UserProfile, but I bet there is a better way...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two general approaches you could take: either update the related field in `post_save()` or use two serializers and require both to be valid before processing the request.

[Check out this question for more details on both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318962/django-rest-framework-flat-read-write-serializer/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up adopting, based on Carlton's linked question (but with some changes since the user needs to be authenticated for the Login, but cannot be authenticated during the Registration:

```
class UserAuthView(APIView):

#Login. Returns the current user.
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Only UserProfileSerializer is required to serialize data
    if (request.user.is_authenticated()):
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(
                instance=request.user.profile)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


#Register new user.
def post(self, request, format=None):
    user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    errors = dict()
    if user_serializer.is_valid():
        user =user_serializer.save()
        data = request.DATA.copy()
        data['user'] = User.objects.latest('id').id
        user_profile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=data)

        if user_profile_serializer.is_valid():
            user_profile_serializer.save()
            return Response(user_profile_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        errors.update(user_profile_serializer.errors)
        return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    errors.update(user_serializer.errors)
    return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```