# Create nested object (1-1 relationship) from flattened POST request

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement two serializer classes which will allow me to create both user and profile objects from a flattened POST request.

I tried the implementation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381700/django-rest-framework-how-do-you-flatten-nested-data) and it works perfectly fine for updating (**and only updating**) existing objects.

Here is my current implementation:

```py
# serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, style={"input_type": "password"}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "username",
            "password",
            # ...
            "date_joined",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("date_joined")


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation.update(representation.pop("user"))
        return representation

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        user_internal = {}
        for key in UserSerializer.Meta.fields:
            if key in data:
                user_internal[key] = data.pop(key)

        internal = super().to_internal_value(data)
        internal["user"] = user_internal
        return internal

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop("user")
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        user.set_password(user_data["password"])
        user.save()

        profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "user",
            "date_updated",
            # ...
            "phone_number",
        )
```

```py
# views.py
class Register(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    name = "userprofile-create"
```

I expect the app to take the flattened JSON and create both user and profile objects.

Example POST body:

```
{
    "username": "test_user",
    "password": "P@$$w0rd",
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Boo",
    "email": "foo@example.com",
    "street": "Random Street",
    "street_number": "11",
    "flat_number": "11",
    "zip_code": "11-111",
    "city": "Some City",
    "province": 1,
    "phone_number": "111222333"
}
```

When I'm browsing through the API, the view still expects JSON with nested User object:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": ""
    },
    "street": "",
    "street_number": "",
    "flat_number": "",
    "zip_code": "",
    "city": "",
    "province": null,
    "phone_number": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding `to_internal_value()` and `to_representation()` wasn't correct approach.

I've created only one serializer with all fields and overriden `create()` method:

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source="user.username")
    password = serializers.CharField(
        source="user.password",
        write_only=True,
        required=True,
        style={"input_type": "password"},
    )
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source="user.first_name")
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source="user.last_name")
    email = serializers.EmailField(source="user.email")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop("user")
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        user.set_password(user_data["password"])
        user.save()

        profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "username",
            "password",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "date_updated",
            "street",
            "street_number",
            "flat_number",
            "zip_code",
            "city",
            "province",
            "phone_number",
        )
```